# Pandas - data per row instead of all in one cell

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have problems getting the data in separate rows. At the moment all my data per column is in one cell. I really would appreciate your support!

the column header is "Dealer" and it is showing one value below like this:
|Dealer|
|:---- |
|['Automobiles', 'Garage Benz', 'Cencini SA']|

I would like to get three rows out of this:

| **Row** | **Dealer** |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 'Automobiles' |
| 2 | 'Garage Benz' |
| 3 | 'Cencini SA' |
| 4 | .... |
| 5 | .... |
| ... | ... |

what would be the easiest way to achieve this?

Thanks for your support, as I am totally new to pandas!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to convert your data into a dict like data:

`x = {'Dealer':['Automobiles', 'Garage Benz', 'Cencini SA']}`

Then

`x = pd.DataFrame(x)`

Comment: This also works for multiple columns? like the location oder zip code of the dealer?

Comment: Yes, just follow the same logic

`x = {'Dealer':['a','b','c'] , 'Zip_code' : [123,345,678]}`

Comment: okay good! That´s is a different way, but I am still getting the same results ... looks like the problem is coming from few lines before... 

At the moment I am getting the data like that:

div2 = page_body.find_all('div',{'class':'seller-info__name text-truncate'})

dealer_name = [divs2.get_text() for divs2 in div2]
print (dealer_name)

Could it be that this is the problem why all data is in one cell?